# Load different js files depending on the page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to optimize the load of all pages on laravel, so I want to load js files only on the pages that use them.

I ended up with a commons js file for all and 3 other js for specific files. Like so:

```
mix   //.scriptsIn('resources/assets/js');
    .scripts([
      // commons
          // cdn
          // 'bootstrap.min.js',
          // 'jquery.min.js',
          'scripts.js',
          'template.js',
      ]);

mix.version(["css/all.css", "js/all.js"]);

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
// welcome page
            'wow.js',
            'jquery.lazyloadxt.extra.min.js',
            // jquery.easing.min.js  // unused
          ], "public/js/welcome.js", 'resources/assets/js');
    mix.version(["js/welcome.js"]);

    mix.scripts([
// chart pages
            'highcharts.js',
            'jquery.highchartTable-min.js',
            ], "public/js/charts.js", 'resources/assets/js');
    mix.version(["js/charts.js"]);

    mix.scripts([
//table pages
            'jquery.tablesorter.min.js',
          ], "public/js/tables.js", 'resources/assets/js');
    mix.version(["js/tables.js"]);

});
```

So I put my all.js on the master view, and what I'd like to do is a way to include the other on just the pages that I want. tables.js only on pages that have a table, and so on.

---

Can I do this without having to manually put the script tag on the individual views?

I'm thinking something like setup a service provider and check for a variable?

```
public function boot()
{
    // view()->composer('master', function ($view) {
    //     $view->with('js_include', 'table.js');
    // });
}
```

And in master view, if exists, include? A page could have table and charts, so I would have to do a foreach. Am I overcomplicating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm doing:

```
public function boot()
{
    $welcome = ['home'];
    $charts = ['meal.*'];
    $tables = ['meal.*', 'trainings.*', 'plans.*', 'nutrition.index',
          'history.index', 'exercises.index'];

    $pages = array_merge($welcome, $charts, $tables);

    foreach ($pages as $key => $page) {
      $js_includes = [];
      foreach (['welcome', 'charts', 'tables'] as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($page, $$value)) $js_includes[] = "js/{$value}.js";
      }

      View::composer($page, function ($view) use ($js_includes) {
          $view->with('js_include', $js_includes);
      });
    }
}
```

In just the master view:

```
@if (isset($js_include))
  @foreach($js_include as $key => $js)
    <script src="/{{ $js }}"></script>    
  @endforeach
@endif
```

It works on localhost but not on heroku deploy :/

I changed `view()->composer` for `View::composer` and added `use View;` but same issue

---

Commenting `//protected $defer = true;` solved the issue

Comment: I had some issues with that before. The problem was, that Laravel did not realize that BladeServiceProvider had changed... can you add something like dd("42") to BladeServiceProvider to see if the Heroku app is really using your version?

Comment: Placing a dd on the service rejects the push, but outputs its value. That's good to know. Commenting     `//protected $defer = true;` solved the issue, but dunno why works on local and not on cloud

Comment: maybe because you are on Heroku in production mode which has a different caching behavior...?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom directive for each of the JS scripts and include the created tag name in the templates.

```
class BladeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('chartsjs', function($expression) {
            return "<?php
               echo '<script type=...>...</script>';
        });     
   } 

   //...
}

// view template: example.blade.php

@section('js')
     @chartsjs
@stop
```

Comment: I have dozens of pages, that's why I'm avoiding to include in each one of them. Shouldn't I have to include that tag in all the templates? It's just less to write then :?

Comment: Yes, it's less to write and you can change things easily (because it's centralized). You could also create different layouts with common partials and do the selection which Javascript is selected there.

Comment: I dont get the advantage other than the less to write. Still have to edit each template separately.

Comment: Let's say you want to rename the script or move it to another folder you can do it once in the BladeServiceProvider.